# how to Call super constructor in Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I have a class

```
@Value
@NonFinal
public class A {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

I have another class B

```
@Value
public class B extends A {
    int z;
}
```

lombok is throwing error saying it cant find A() constructor, explicitly call it what i want lombok to do is to give annotation to class b such that  it generates the following code:

```
public class B extends A {
    int z;
    public B( int x, int y, int z) {
        super( x , y );
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Do we have an annotation to do that in Lombok?

Answer (score 314):

This is not possible in Lombok. Although it would be a really nice feature, it requires resolution to find the constructors of the super class. The super class is only known by name the moment Lombok gets invoked. Using the import statements and the classpath to find the actual class is not trivial. And during compilation you cannot just use reflection to get a list of constructors.

It is not entirely impossible but the results using resolution in `val` and `@ExtensionMethod` have taught us that is it hard and error-prone.

Disclosure: I am a Lombok developer.

Comment: @roel-spilker We understand the complexities behind it. But can Lombok provide an `inConstructor` method for constructor annotations where we can specify which constructor of `super` shall Lombok inject in the generated constructor?

Comment: afterConstructor would be nice as well to do some automatic initialization

Comment: @Manu/@Pawel: see lombok enhancement request: https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/issues/78  (currently open)

Comment: Since @Builder is in official release see: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/853

Comment: @Roel
Is it possible to make something like a `@CopyConstructor`? This way we can annotate the `class Base` with it and in the `class Der extends Base`  the following will be short and easy to be done manually:
`public Der(Base base, Object extraProp) { super(base); this.extraProp = extraProp; }`

Comment: Hi Roel Spilker, Can we try to generate the child class' constructor from the other side? I mean that the @RequiredArgsConstructor may have a switch to generate ctors in the child classes and delegate them all to the parent with the annotation maybe or something similar?

Comment: Late thought: It would probably be possible to manually pass delegate arguments to `@Value` in a `parentArgs` parameter or similar? Probably would still look cleaner than writing the constructor by hand in an environment that otherwise uses Lombok.

Answer (score 40):

Version 1.18 of Lombok introduced the @SuperBuilder annotation. We can use this to solve our problem in a simpler way.

You can refer to https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-inheritance#lombok-builder-and-inheritance-3.

so in your child class, you will need these annotations:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
```

in your parent class:

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
```

Comment: With SuperBuilder, does AllArgsConstructor then include parameters from both parent and child? Thanks!

Comment: We cannot solve this in case when SuperBuilder is not needed in result class. Especially when this builder is far away from ideal. In my case my builders always doing deep copy, lombok's - no.

Comment: java: Generating equals/hashCode with a supercall to java.lang.Object is pointless.

Answer (score 30):

[Lombok Issue #78](https://github.com/peichhorn/lombok-pg/issues/78) references this page https://www.donneo.de/2015/09/16/lomboks-builder-annotation-and-inheritance/ with this lovely explanation:

> ```
> @AllArgsConstructor 
> public class Parent {   
>      private String a; 
> }
>
> public class Child extends Parent {
>   private String b;
>
>   @Builder
>   public Child(String a, String b){
>     super(a);
>     this.b = b;   
>   } 
> }
> ```
>
> As a result you can then use the generated builder like this:
>
> ```
> Child.builder().a("testA").b("testB").build();
> ```
>
> The [official documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder.html) explains this, but it doesn’t explicitly point out that you can facilitate it in this way.

I also found this works nicely with Spring Data JPA.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this being used with Spring Data JPA?

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. Instead, it does the work by hand, while the question was how to generate it. At the same time, it makes the whole thing more confusing by dragging @Builder, which does not have anything to do with the question.

Comment: Actually this is very useful for those who just want to create an inheritance structure and then use builder. This is 99% reason I use #lombok anyways. Sometimes we just have to handcraft stuffs to make it work the way we desire.So thanks @jj-zabkar

Comment: but then; simply code the self+parent arg constructor. No need to use a builder

Comment: It'll work in STS & eclipse, but when you generate JAR file of your application, most probably it will fail. I tried Both SuperBuilder, Builder for inheritence. Both got failed. Be careful !!

Comment: What if there are 3 classes such thast Class C extends Class B and Class B extends Class A?

Answer (score 12):

Lombok does not support that also indicated by making any `@Value` annotated class `final` (as you know by using `@NonFinal`).

The only workaround I found is to declare all members final yourself and use the `@Data` annotation instead. Those subclasses need to be annotated by `@EqualsAndHashCode` and need an explicit all args constructor as Lombok doesn't know how to create one using the all args one of the super class:

```
@Data
public class A {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class B extends A {
    private final int z;

    public B(int x, int y, int z) {
        super(x, y);
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Especially the constructors of the subclasses make the solution a little untidy for superclasses with many members, sorry.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more why "subclasses need to be annotated by `@EqualsAndHashCode`"? Isn't this annotation included by `@Data`? Thx :)

Comment: @GerardB `@Data` also creates equals() and hashCode() but don't cares about any inheritance. To make sure the superclass equals() and hashCode() is used, you need the explicit generation with callSuper

Comment: I thought class B could be @Value. Can it? So JVM would be able to optimize its performance by storing on Stack.

Answer (score 7):

for superclasses with many members I would suggest you to use @Delegate

```
@Data
public class A {
    @Delegate public class AInner{
        private final int x;
        private final int y;
    }
}

@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class B extends A {
    private final int z;

    public B(A.AInner a, int z) {
        super(a);
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, like it!

Comment: `@Delegate` is `@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD})`. `AInner `should be field in `A`.

Answer (score 3):

If child class has more members, than parent, it could be done not very clean, but short way:

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public class User extends BaseEntity {
    private @NonNull String fullName;
    private @NonNull String email;
    ... 

    public User(Integer id, String fullName, String email, ....) {
        this(fullName, email, ....);
        this.id = id;
    }
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
abstract public class BaseEntity {
   protected Integer id;

   public boolean isNew() {
      return id == null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Instance variables should not be made protected lightheartedly, as it most probably violates object orientation principles.