# Is it possible to construct a derived class instance from a base class instance using lombok?

Tags: java, lombok

Using lombok, I am interested to copy all the fields from a base class instance to the derived class via its constructor, very similar to what C++ copy constructor does. Presently concern is not so much on whether the copy is deep or shallow.
I have a base class as shown below,

```
class Parent {
  .... fields
}
```

and I am interested to automatically generate a derived class constructor which takes base class instance and copy (either shallow or deep) all the fields to the derived one. e.g.

```
class Child extends Parent {
   ... derived fields
   Child(Parent p) { // can be implemented as super(p); 
   }
}
```

I have the flexibility to annotate both *Parent* and *Child* class as needed, however do not want to handcraft the constructor, which copies each fields one by one. 
Example usage

```
Parent parent = Parent.of(....);
Child child = new Child(parent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the functionality for copy constructor isn't there yet([github issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/908))

And also its not possible to generate constructors calling super(stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771875/4308639) and [github issue](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1229)), because:

> getting to the parent class required resolution, it is simply not possible.

So based on this I think it's not possible to do that, currently

Comment: @vmrvictor It was opened few years ago when I was answering question above. Now it seems they've eventually decided not to implement this, please refer to this comment: https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/908#issuecomment-430001916