# Java Lombok library : builder annotation issues with Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, lombok

Java Lombok library : builder annotation issues with Inheritance

```
    @Builder
    public class ParentClass {
        private final String a;
        private final String b;
    }

    @Builder
    public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
        private final String c;
    }
```

When creating an instance of child class, parent class attributes are not visible with Builder annotations.

Below fails:

```
     ChildClass.builder().a("testA").b("testB").c("testC").build();
```

However, below statement is correct:

```
     ChildClass.builder().c("testC").build();
```

Seems this issue is open for long time, dont know if any latest release has any fixes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest lombok release 1.18.2 includes [the new experimental `@SuperBuilder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder). It was added exactly for this: setting fields from superclasses.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I was able to resolve above issue with @SuperBuilder annotation introduced as experimental in lombok release 1.18.2.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you define ParentClass with @Builder annotation it creates ParentClass(String) constructor and deletes implicit one. Then Child class cannot even be created.
Please look at the following answer:
[how to Call super constructor in Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740078/how-to-call-super-constructor-in-lombok)