# A minimized version of setting all values in the constructor using Lombok instead of downcasting with additional setter

Tags: java, casting, lombok

I am trying to use Lombok to minimise the line of codes I have to write to convert superclass object to a subclass object.

SuperClass:

```
@Data
public class SuperClass{
// lots of fields
}
```

SubClass:

```
@Data
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
private String additionalField;

public SubClass(SuperClass super, String additionalField){
  // set all available fields from superclass
  this.additionalField = additionalField;
  }
}
```

I trivial solution is to accept all arguments and set them accordingly, but I am looking for a minimum model that I need to only pass the additional arguments to the constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740078/how-to-call-super-constructor-in-lombok.
Also, not sure how this is relevant to `downcasting`

Comment: That question is actually touching on a different aspect, so I don't think it helps.

Comment: Does `SuperClass` have an existing constructor that accepts `//lots of fields`?

Comment: @SeanMickey  I can add '@AllArgsConstructor' to have that contractor, but it means I need to pass every field one by one in the SubClass constructor. I am mostly looking for an approach to take the SuperClass object and set them accordingly.