# Google Guice and Lombok - @AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject)) for abstract class

Tags: java, guice, lombok

I find `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))` is helpful to keep code clean when working with Google Guice. I can save the constructor code. For example:

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public class SomeClass {
    private final DependentClassOne classOne;
    private final DependentClassTwo classTwo;

    // ...
}
```

For `abstract` class, I'm able to use `@Inject` for constructor.

```
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))
public abstract class AbstractParentClass {
    private final DependentClassOne classOne;
}

public class ChildClass extends AbstractParentClass {
    private final DependentClassTwo classTwo;

    @Inject
    public ChildClass(final DependentClassOne classOne, final DependentClassTwo classTwo) {
        super(classOne);
        this.classTwo = classTwo;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to save the constructor code in `ChildClass` by using something like `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Inject))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to define `AllArgsConstructor` in child class when there is parent constructor due to the limitation of Lombok (see this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1229) and another [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29771875/6099243)).

You could mix field/setter injection in parent with constructor injection in child, but I would advise to avoid it.