# Lombok subclass constructor @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I have superclass:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractSuperService {
     protected final SuperRepository superRepository;
  
}
```

And two subclass:

```
@Service
public class OneSubService extends AbstractSuperService {
     private final OneRepository oneRepository;
     
     public OneSubService(SuperRepository superRepository, OneRepository oneRepository){
         super(superRepository);
         this.oneRepository = oneRepository;
    }
}


@Service
public class SecondSubService extends AbstractSuperService {
     private final SecondRepository secondRepository;

     public SecondSubService(SuperRepository superRepository, SecondRepository secondRepository){
         super(superRepository);
         this.secondRepository = secondRepository;
    }
}
```

This code is work.
But if I change code: delete constructor in subclasses and add annotation lombok @SuperBuilder in all class.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class AbstractSuperService {
     protected final SuperRepository superRepository;
  
}

@Service
@SuperBuilder
public class OneSubService extends AbstractSuperService {
     private final OneRepository oneRepository;
     
}


@Service
@SuperBuilder
public class SecondSubService extends AbstractSuperService {
     private final SecondRepository secondRepository;

}
```

The following error appears:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in OneSubService required a bean of type 'OneSubService$OneSubServiceBuilder' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'OneSubService$OneSubServiceBuilder' in your configuration.
```

How to correctly apply the lombok annotation in subclass, so as not to write constructor in subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `@SuperBuilder`, no constructor is created.
In Spring in order to inject `OneRepository` and `SuperRepository`, you need a constructor having these two objects as parameters.

Using `@AllArgConstructor`, Lombok creates the constructor just for the members of that class, not considering the super class.
*Why? You can read the answer of a Lombok developer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740078/how-to-call-super-constructor-in-lombok).*

In the end, your first solution is a unique solution if you want to have a super class.