# Lombok does not include super in AllArgsConstructor - Inheritance from abstract and generic class

Tags: java, spring-boot, model-view-controller, lombok

I do have a problem in my Spring Boot application regarding the inheritance from a parent class (abstract and generic). Below I have built a simple example to simplify my issue:

**Parent Class:**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public abstract class GenericEntity<T> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

**Child Class:**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Employee extends GenericEntity<Employee> implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    // Rest of attributes which map my columns in MySQL table employee (see below)

    // I want lombok to do this:
    public Employee(Long empId, String firstName, String lastName){
        super(empId); // I need to rename "id" to "empId" and map it with PK in table employee "emp_id"
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // Getters and Setters (done by Lombok @Getter / @Setter)
}

/* DESCRIBE employee;
 *
+------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| emp_id           | int                   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name_prefix      | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| first_name       | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_name        | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gender           | enum('Male','Female') | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_of_joining  | date                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title            | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_of_birth    | date                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| salary           | double                | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ssn              | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| city             | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| zip              | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| state            | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country          | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| married          | tinyint(1)            | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_of_marriage | date                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| no_of_children   | int                   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| degree           | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| citizenship      | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| country_of_birth | varchar(45)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| dep_id           | int                   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| man_id           | int                   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| comp_id          | int                   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
 */
```

Of course the next challenge would be to rename in my `Employee.java` entity class the id to `empId` or specifying with the `@Column(name = "emp_id")` annotation the mapping to the primary key.

The goal is to reuse predefined functions in my generic Service class and inheriting them in multiple service classes later for my remaining MySQL Tables / entities. The generic helps me to use similar functions (optionally by overriding them) for the rest of my entities (deparmtent, company, credential, etc.).

Because I do get always this error, I hope to find a lombok-based solution, otherwise I do have no alternative than defining the constructor manually.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to Call super constructor in Lombok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740078/how-to-call-super-constructor-in-lombok)

Comment: …and while beginners write down the Java code in minutes, experts waste hours of research trying to make Lombok generate the code…

Comment: Thank you @racraman for the suggestion. I have already seen that post, but unfortunately it didn't helped. Nevertheless, thank you very much.